varchar or blob for encoded data
I plan to store a lot of customer responses in a table I have used snappy.compress with utf_8 but now the table seems to occupy more spaces I tried with varchar and blob and blob seems to take twice the size.Why is this so?

When you need to store binary data then you must use any binary strings datatype which have BINARY character set. The string-type column with UTF8 character set is NOT binary string.

You haven't shown an example of the data, or the code you use to insert it into the database, or the method you used to measure the size. So there's no way to answer this question except by guessing.

Compressed data must be stored in BLOB or BINARY.
